# I have two columns in a pandas dataframe. One column has some same values (id) and corresponding values in another column has Number of tickets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
   id         n_tickets
0  1586391          2
1   640             2
2   640             1
3  1181593          2
4   964842          1
5    780            1
6    780            1
```

I have the above data frame. As you can see that in id column 640 and 780 have occurred two times. I want that just a single occurrence remains but there corresponding values in column n_tickets gets added up. My final dataframe should look like this:

```
     id         n_tickets
0  1586391          2
1   640             3
2  1181593          2
3   964842          1
4    780            2
```

I am using the code: `df_tickets.groupby(['id','n_tickets']).sum()`but I am gettting the error:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

when i use the below code:

```
df_tickets.groupby('id',sort=False).sum().reset_index()

print(df_tickets.loc[df_tickets['id'] == 780])
```

I get this:

```
        id     n_tickets
425166  780          1
985855  780          1
```

Instead I should get:

```
           id    n_tickets
   425166  780      2
```

Comment: That's not an error, just an unexpected result. There is no reason to also `groupby` on `n_tickets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to group by 'id':

```
df.groupby('id',sort=False).sum().reset_index()
Out[60]: 
        id  n_tickets
0  1586391          2
1      640          3
2  1181593          2
3   964842          1
4      780          2
```

when i use the above code:

```
df_tickets.groupby('id',sort=False).sum().reset_index()

    print(df_tickets.loc[df_tickets['id'] == 780])
```

I get this:

```
         id     n_tickets
425166  780          1
985855  780          1
```

Instead I should get:

```
    id    n_tickets
 425166  780      2
```

Comment: I have a big data set. Even after applying the above code, I am not able to drop the dplicates. Here is the result: 465654  645          4
755874  645          6. Here 465654 and 755874 are indexes and I wanr ro keep just one 645 and corresponding value as 10

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
df_tickets = df_tickets.groupby(df_tickets['id']).sum()
```

This should work.

Comment: I have a big data set. Even after applying the above code, I am not able to drop the dplicates. Here is the result: 465654 645 4 755874 645 6. Here 465654 and 755874 are indexes and I want to keep just one 645 and corresponding value as 10.